# Cloning a git repo, and it already has a dirty working directory... Whaaaaa?

Tags: git

So, I'm confused as to what's going on. I've never hacked on the linux kernel, so maybe this is commonplace. If that's the case, sorry for the newb question.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
```

Then,

```
$ git status
```

.

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
#   modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h
#   modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_MARK.h
#   modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.h
#   modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.h
#   modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h
#   modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_TTL.h
#   modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_HL.h
#   modified:   net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ECN.c
#   modified:   net/netfilter/xt_DSCP.c
#   modified:   net/netfilter/xt_HL.c
#   modified:   net/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.c
#   modified:   net/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.c
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   samples/hidraw/
```

What's the deal?

**EDIT** :  git diff output:

```
diff --git a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
index 2f2e48e..efc17a8 100644
--- a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
+++ b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
@@ -1,6 +1,31 @@
-#ifndef _XT_CONNMARK_H_target
-#define _XT_CONNMARK_H_target
+#ifndef _XT_CONNMARK_H
+#define _XT_CONNMARK_H

-#include <linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h>
+#include <linux/types.h>

-#endif /*_XT_CONNMARK_H_target*/
+/* Copyright (C) 2002,2004 MARA Systems AB <http://www.marasystems.com>
+ * by Henrik Nordstrom <hno@marasystems.com>
+ *
+ * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
+ * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
+ * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
+ * (at your option) any later version.
+ */
+
+enum {
+   XT_CONNMARK_SET = 0,
+   XT_CONNMARK_SAVE,
+   XT_CONNMARK_RESTORE
+};
+
+struct xt_connmark_tginfo1 {
+   __u32 ctmark, ctmask, nfmask;
+   __u8 mode;
+};
+
+struct xt_connmark_mtinfo1 {
+   __u32 mark, mask;
+   __u8 invert;
+};
+
+#endif /*_XT_CONNMARK_H*/
diff --git a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h
index 648e0b3..15f8932 100644
--- a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h
+++ b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h
@@ -1,26 +1,31 @@
-/* x_tables module for setting the IPv4/IPv6 DSCP field
+/* x_tables module for matching the IPv4/IPv6 DSCP field
  *
  * (C) 2002 Harald Welte <laforge@gnumonks.org>
- * based on ipt_FTOS.c (C) 2000 by Matthew G. Marsh <mgm@paktronix.com>
  * This software is distributed under GNU GPL v2, 1991
  *
  * See RFC2474 for a description of the DSCP field within the IP Header.
  *
- * xt_DSCP.h,v 1.7 2002/03/14 12:03:13 laforge Exp
+ * xt_dscp.h,v 1.3 2002/08/05 19:00:21 laforge Exp
 */
-#ifndef _XT_DSCP_TARGET_H
-#define _XT_DSCP_TARGET_H
-#include <linux/netfilter/xt_dscp.h>
+#ifndef _XT_DSCP_H
+#define _XT_DSCP_H
+
 #include <linux/types.h>

-/* target info */
-struct xt_DSCP_info {
+#define XT_DSCP_MASK   0xfc    /* 11111100 */
+#define XT_DSCP_SHIFT  2
+#define XT_DSCP_MAX    0x3f    /* 00111111 */
+
+/* match info */
+struct xt_dscp_info {
    __u8 dscp;
+   __u8 invert;
 };

-struct xt_tos_target_info {
-   __u8 tos_value;
+struct xt_tos_match_info {
    __u8 tos_mask;
+   __u8 tos_value;
+   __u8 invert;
 };

-#endif /* _XT_DSCP_TARGET_H */
+#endif /* _XT_DSCP_H */
diff --git a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_MARK.h b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_MARK.h
index 41c456d..ecadc40 100644
--- a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_MARK.h
+++ b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_MARK.h
@@ -1,6 +1,15 @@
-#ifndef _XT_MARK_H_target
-#define _XT_MARK_H_target
+#ifndef _XT_MARK_H
+#define _XT_MARK_H

-#include <linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h>
+#include <linux/types.h>

-#endif /*_XT_MARK_H_target */
+struct xt_mark_tginfo2 {
+   __u32 mark, mask;
+};
+
+struct xt_mark_mtinfo1 {
+   __u32 mark, mask;
+   __u8 invert;
+};
+
+#endif /*_XT_MARK_H*/
diff --git a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.h b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.h
index 6605e20..d40a619 100644
--- a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.h
+++ b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.h
@@ -1,15 +1,37 @@
-#ifndef _XT_RATEEST_TARGET_H
-#define _XT_RATEEST_TARGET_H
+#ifndef _XT_RATEEST_MATCH_H
+#define _XT_RATEEST_MATCH_H

 #include <linux/types.h>

-struct xt_rateest_target_info {
-   char            name[IFNAMSIZ];
-   __s8            interval;
-   __u8        ewma_log;
+enum xt_rateest_match_flags {
+   XT_RATEEST_MATCH_INVERT = 1<<0,
+   XT_RATEEST_MATCH_ABS    = 1<<1,
+   XT_RATEEST_MATCH_REL    = 1<<2,
+   XT_RATEEST_MATCH_DELTA  = 1<<3,
+   XT_RATEEST_MATCH_BPS    = 1<<4,
+   XT_RATEEST_MATCH_PPS    = 1<<5,
+};
+
+enum xt_rateest_match_mode {
+   XT_RATEEST_MATCH_NONE,
+   XT_RATEEST_MATCH_EQ,
+   XT_RATEEST_MATCH_LT,
+   XT_RATEEST_MATCH_GT,
+};
+
+struct xt_rateest_match_info {
+   char            name1[IFNAMSIZ];
+   char            name2[IFNAMSIZ];
+   __u16       flags;
+   __u16       mode;
+   __u32       bps1;
+   __u32       pps1;
+   __u32       bps2;
+   __u32       pps2;

    /* Used internally by the kernel */
-   struct xt_rateest   *est __attribute__((aligned(8)));
+   struct xt_rateest   *est1 __attribute__((aligned(8)));
+   struct xt_rateest   *est2 __attribute__((aligned(8)));
 };

-#endif /* _XT_RATEEST_TARGET_H */
+#endif /* _XT_RATEEST_MATCH_H */
diff --git a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.h b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.h
index 9a6960a..fbac56b 100644
--- a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.h
+++ b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.h
@@ -1,12 +1,11 @@
-#ifndef _XT_TCPMSS_H
-#define _XT_TCPMSS_H
+#ifndef _XT_TCPMSS_MATCH_H
+#define _XT_TCPMSS_MATCH_H

 #include <linux/types.h>

-struct xt_tcpmss_info {
-   __u16 mss;
+struct xt_tcpmss_match_info {
+    __u16 mss_min, mss_max;
+    __u8 invert;
 };

-#define XT_TCPMSS_CLAMP_PMTU 0xffff
-
-#endif /* _XT_TCPMSS_H */
+#endif /*_XT_TCPMSS_MATCH_H*/
diff --git a/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h b/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h
index bb88d53..eabf95f 100644
--- a/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h
+++ b/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h
@@ -1,33 +1,35 @@
-/* Header file for iptables ipt_ECN target
+/* iptables module for matching the ECN header in IPv4 and TCP header
  *
- * (C) 2002 by Harald Welte <laforge@gnumonks.org>
+ * (C) 2002 Harald Welte <laforge@gnumonks.org>
  *
  * This software is distributed under GNU GPL v2, 1991
  * 
- * ipt_ECN.h,v 1.3 2002/05/29 12:17:40 laforge Exp
+ * ipt_ecn.h,v 1.4 2002/08/05 19:39:00 laforge Exp
 */
-#ifndef _IPT_ECN_TARGET_H
-#define _IPT_ECN_TARGET_H
+#ifndef _IPT_ECN_H
+#define _IPT_ECN_H

 #include <linux/types.h>
-#include <linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h>
+#include <linux/netfilter/xt_dscp.h>

 #define IPT_ECN_IP_MASK    (~XT_DSCP_MASK)

-#define IPT_ECN_OP_SET_IP  0x01    /* set ECN bits of IPv4 header */
-#define IPT_ECN_OP_SET_ECE 0x10    /* set ECE bit of TCP header */
-#define IPT_ECN_OP_SET_CWR 0x20    /* set CWR bit of TCP header */
+#define IPT_ECN_OP_MATCH_IP    0x01
+#define IPT_ECN_OP_MATCH_ECE   0x10
+#define IPT_ECN_OP_MATCH_CWR   0x20

-#define IPT_ECN_OP_MASK        0xce
+#define IPT_ECN_OP_MATCH_MASK  0xce

-struct ipt_ECN_info {
-   __u8 operation; /* bitset of operations */
-   __u8 ip_ect;    /* ECT codepoint of IPv4 header, pre-shifted */
+/* match info */
+struct ipt_ecn_info {
+   __u8 operation;
+   __u8 invert;
+   __u8 ip_ect;
    union {
        struct {
-           __u8 ece:1, cwr:1; /* TCP ECT bits */
+           __u8 ect;
        } tcp;
    } proto;
 };

-#endif /* _IPT_ECN_TARGET_H */
+#endif /* _IPT_ECN_H */
diff --git a/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_TTL.h b/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_TTL.h
index f6ac169..37bee44 100644
--- a/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_TTL.h
+++ b/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_TTL.h
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
-/* TTL modification module for IP tables
- * (C) 2000 by Harald Welte <laforge@netfilter.org> */
+/* IP tables module for matching the value of the TTL
+ * (C) 2000 by Harald Welte <laforge@gnumonks.org> */

 #ifndef _IPT_TTL_H
 #define _IPT_TTL_H
@@ -7,14 +7,14 @@
 #include <linux/types.h>

 enum {
-   IPT_TTL_SET = 0,
-   IPT_TTL_INC,
-   IPT_TTL_DEC
+   IPT_TTL_EQ = 0,     /* equals */
+   IPT_TTL_NE,     /* not equals */
+   IPT_TTL_LT,     /* less than */
+   IPT_TTL_GT,     /* greater than */
 };

-#define IPT_TTL_MAXMODE    IPT_TTL_DEC

-struct ipt_TTL_info {
+struct ipt_ttl_info {
    __u8    mode;
    __u8    ttl;
 };
diff --git a/include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_HL.h b/include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_HL.h
index ebd8ead..6e76dbc 100644
--- a/include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_HL.h
+++ b/include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_HL.h
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
-/* Hop Limit modification module for ip6tables
+/* ip6tables module for matching the Hop Limit value
  * Maciej Soltysiak <solt@dns.toxicfilms.tv>
- * Based on HW's TTL module */
+ * Based on HW's ttl module */

 #ifndef _IP6T_HL_H
 #define _IP6T_HL_H
@@ -8,14 +8,14 @@
 #include <linux/types.h>

 enum {
-   IP6T_HL_SET = 0,
-   IP6T_HL_INC,
-   IP6T_HL_DEC
+   IP6T_HL_EQ = 0,     /* equals */
+   IP6T_HL_NE,     /* not equals */
+   IP6T_HL_LT,     /* less than */
+   IP6T_HL_GT,     /* greater than */
 };

-#define IP6T_HL_MAXMODE    IP6T_HL_DEC

-struct ip6t_HL_info {
+struct ip6t_hl_info {
    __u8    mode;
    __u8    hop_limit;
 };
diff --git a/net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ECN.c b/net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ECN.c
index 4bf3dc4..2b57e52 100644
--- a/net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ECN.c
+++ b/net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ECN.c
@@ -1,138 +1,127 @@
-/* iptables module for the IPv4 and TCP ECN bits, Version 1.5
+/* IP tables module for matching the value of the IPv4 and TCP ECN bits
  *
- * (C) 2002 by Harald Welte <laforge@netfilter.org>
+ * (C) 2002 by Harald Welte <laforge@gnumonks.org>
  *
  * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
  * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
  * published by the Free Software Foundation.
-*/
+ */
 #define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt
 #include <linux/in.h>
-#include <linux/module.h>
-#include <linux/skbuff.h>
 #include <linux/ip.h>
 #include <net/ip.h>
+#include <linux/module.h>
+#include <linux/skbuff.h>
 #include <linux/tcp.h>
-#include <net/checksum.h>

 #include <linux/netfilter/x_tables.h>
 #include <linux/netfilter_ipv4/ip_tables.h>
-#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h>
+#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ecn.h>

-MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
 MODULE_AUTHOR("Harald Welte <laforge@netfilter.org>");
-MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Xtables: Explicit Congestion Notification (ECN) flag modification");
+MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Xtables: Explicit Congestion Notification (ECN) flag match for IPv4");
+MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

-/* set ECT codepoint from IP header.
- *     return false if there was an error. */
-static inline bool
-set_ect_ip(struct sk_buff *skb, const struct ipt_ECN_info *einfo)
+static inline bool match_ip(const struct sk_buff *skb,
+               const struct ipt_ecn_info *einfo)
 {
-   struct iphdr *iph = ip_hdr(skb);
-
-   if ((iph->tos & IPT_ECN_IP_MASK) != (einfo->ip_ect & IPT_ECN_IP_MASK)) {
-       __u8 oldtos;
-       if (!skb_make_writable(skb, sizeof(struct iphdr)))
-           return false;
-       iph = ip_hdr(skb);
-       oldtos = iph->tos;
-       iph->tos &= ~IPT_ECN_IP_MASK;
-       iph->tos |= (einfo->ip_ect & IPT_ECN_IP_MASK);
-       csum_replace2(&iph->check, htons(oldtos), htons(iph->tos));
-   }
-   return true;
+   return ((ip_hdr(skb)->tos & IPT_ECN_IP_MASK) == einfo->ip_ect) ^
+          !!(einfo->invert & IPT_ECN_OP_MATCH_IP);
 }

-/* Return false if there was an error. */
-static inline bool
-set_ect_tcp(struct sk_buff *skb, const struct ipt_ECN_info *einfo)
+static inline bool match_tcp(const struct sk_buff *skb,
+                const struct ipt_ecn_info *einfo,
+                bool *hotdrop)
 {
-   struct tcphdr _tcph, *tcph;
-   __be16 oldval;
-
-   /* Not enough header? */
-   tcph = skb_header_pointer(skb, ip_hdrlen(skb), sizeof(_tcph), &_tcph);
-   if (!tcph)
+   struct tcphdr _tcph;
+   const struct tcphdr *th;
+
+   /* In practice, TCP match does this, so can't fail.  But let's
+    * be good citizens.
+    */
+   th = skb_header_pointer(skb, ip_hdrlen(skb), sizeof(_tcph), &_tcph);
+   if (th == NULL) {
+       *hotdrop = false;
        return false;
+   }

-   if ((!(einfo->operation & IPT_ECN_OP_SET_ECE) ||
-        tcph->ece == einfo->proto.tcp.ece) &&
-       (!(einfo->operation & IPT_ECN_OP_SET_CWR) ||
-        tcph->cwr == einfo->proto.tcp.cwr))
-       return true;
-
-   if (!skb_make_writable(skb, ip_hdrlen(skb) + sizeof(*tcph)))
-       return false;
-   tcph = (void *)ip_hdr(skb) + ip_hdrlen(skb);
```

...

(Truncated because it will exceed the stackoveflow post body limit otherwise.)

Comment: I have zero experience with that particular repository, but gut instinct says it's something to do with line endings or character encodings. Try typing `git diff` and seeing what Git *thinks* is different. Then get back to us with that info.

Comment: Somehow the checkout probably screwed with the line endings. `git diff` will show you that the end of line character has changed on all those files. Someone else can find the configuration you need to stop this. `git reset --hard HEAD` is a work-around, but it only temporarily fixes the issue.

Comment: A bunch of things could have happened. You, or someone else, may have changed file permissions with a recursive `chown` (Which git considers modified). There could have been a text conversion between linebreak character types (`'\r\n'` to `'\n'`, etc). Probably some other things like that I don't know about.

Comment: my git diff shows legitimate code changes, not just line endings. This is odd.

Comment: Also, @Stefan-Kendall, I tried `git reset --hard HEAD` and it has no effect!

Comment: Have you cloned to a location inside an existing git clone? Did you cd into the new `linux` directory before running git status?

Comment: Cloned in an empty directory. Tried this twice

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893827/strange-behaviour-of-git-mysterious-changes-cannot-be-undone

Comment: You will now (Q4 2018, Git 2.20) be warned during a git clone with any case-sensitive overshadowing: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451244/6309).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This error is caused by your filesystem not being case sensitive, like the default on Mac OS X.

Comment: Maybe I misread this answer, but Mac OS X is indeed case sensitive as far as I know. Windows isn't.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña: No it isn't. Try `touch abc; touch ABC` and see how many files you end up with.

Comment: @MarceloCantos thanks, since I posted that comment I have indeed learned it is case insensitive :)

Comment: Its really about the default fileystem in OSX, its possible to create a case sensitive partition

Comment: this is not an answer. I know which operating system I'm using.

Answer (score 9):

So, you've checked out linux sources on a filesystem that isn't case sensitive. That's the problem. Try checking out on ext2 partition.

As a workaround you can also use git sparsecheckout feature:

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo /* > .git/info/sparse-checkout 
echo !include/linux/netfilter/ > .git/info/sparse-checkout 
echo !include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ > .git/info/sparse-checkout 
echo !include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ > .git/info/sparse-checkout 
echo !net/ipv4/netfilter/ > .git/info/sparse-checkout 
echo !net/netfilter > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git read-tree --reset -u HEAD
```

Comment: I believe you need to change all but the first of those `>`s into `>>`s, and quote the `/*` and all the `!`s.

Comment: @RadonRosborough you're right, I didn't test this script. Just illustrated the idea.

Comment: Thanks! Shame on `netfilter`. It's not unusual to use a Mac as a source code editor for a project that includes the kernel. I know that a case-sensitive volume can be created with a nearly zero overhead, but even that is a waste of time.

Comment: @VictorSergienko yeah, Mac's partition is case insensitive by default too. I hope eventually Apple and Microsoft will bend the knee and ease the pain for developers.

Answer (score 7):

> This error is caused by your filesystem not being case sensitive

You should not have to *guess* anymore, not with Git 2.20 (Q4 2018, seven years later after the OP)

It is true that running "`git clone`" against a project that contain two files with pathnames differing only in cases on a case insensitive filesystem would result in one of the files lost because the underlying filesystem is incapable of holding both at the same time.
But now... an attempt is made to **detect such a case and warn**.

See [commit b878579](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b878579ae755e3a9d200093ced59ada3eaafb08c) (17 Aug 2018) by [Duy Nguyen (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c240732](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2407322b6f248955d8ce8d1d453f2dc1b03e618), 17 Sep 2018)</sup>

> ### `clone`: report duplicate entries on case-insensitive filesystems
>
> Paths that only differ in case work fine in a case-sensitive filesystems, but if those repos are cloned in a case-insensitive one, you'll get problems. The first thing to notice is "`git status`" will never be clean with no indication what exactly is "`dirty`".
>
> This patch helps the situation a bit by pointing out the problem at clone time.
>   Even though this patch talks about case sensitivity, the patch makes no assumption about folding rules by the filesystem. It simply observes that if an entry has been already checked out at clone time when we're about to write a new path, some folding rules are behind this.
>
> In the case that we can't rely on filesystem (via `inode` number) to do this check, fall back to `fspathcmp()` which is not perfect but should not give false positives.

You can see [`unpack-trees.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c2407322b6f248955d8ce8d1d453f2dc1b03e618/unpack-trees.c) with a new [`report_collided_checkout()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c2407322b6f248955d8ce8d1d453f2dc1b03e618/unpack-trees.c#L349-L370) function, which will display the warning:

```
the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths
on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same
colliding group is in the working tree:
```

No more surprises here.

---

[codewarrior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221433/codewarrior) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383426/cloning-a-git-repo-and-it-already-has-a-dirty-working-directory-whaaaaa/56780103#comment100115258_52451244) that Windows does support now (2018-2019) case sensitive filesystem with `fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo C:\a\path enable` ...
Yes but, as seen in [`MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs` issue 977](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/issues/977):

> **You have to enable [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) before this will work**.
>
> Run the following command as Administrator in PowerShell to enable this optional feature:
>
> ```
> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
> ```
>
> You'll be prompted to restart your machine once it's installed.
>   After your computer restarts, you'll be able to run `Fsutil` as Administrator in a command prompt window as you expected.

See "[Per-directory case sensitivity and WSL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/)"

> Starting with Windows insider build 17093, we’ve introduced a new way to handle case sensitive files in Windows: **per-directory case sensitivity**.
>   We use this ability in the Windows Subsystem for Linux to give you better interoperability when using case sensitive files, and you can also use it yourself with regular Windows applications.
>
> Starting with build 17110, DrvFs’s default behavior is now equivalent to using “`case=dir`”.
>   This means that any directories you created with WSL before build 17093 will not be treated as case sensitive anymore. To fix this, use fsutil.exe to mark your existing directories as case sensitive.

Comment: Windows now supports case sensitive: 
fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo <folder path> enable

Comment: @codewarrior True, although you need to activate WSL. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 6):

Hit the same problem but it has been almost 8 years, Windows now supports case sensitive folder.

```
fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo <folder path> enable
```

Then resync the folder.
Note this will not affect subdirectory so need to run this command for every folder.

Comment: After cloning into a case sensitive folder (i have identical situation as op with the netfilter headers), git strangely reports 8 changes when I run git status, but no changes when I run git diff or git stash. It correctly doesn't set the local config to core.ignorecase=true, but still isn't completely case sensitive, as status doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The comments are most likely correct in their suspicion of line endings. Try setting this option:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Then re-clone the repository.

Use a value of `true` on windows and `input` on OSX/Unix.

Take a look at [this Github help page](http://help.github.com/line-endings/) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is `git mv`:

```
$ git mv include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h2
```

Then you have

```
$ git status
...
    renamed:    include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h -> include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h2
...
    deleted     include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
```

Then cancel the changes:

```
$ git checkout include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
```

After that you have have:

```
$ ls -la
include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h2
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is `git update-index --refresh` in case somehow the cache of filestat information got wonked in the process of cloning (maybe by an `ntpd` clock adjustment or such?). If that doesn't help, we'll probably need to know what the output of `git diff` looks like to help you more.