# How can I discard modified files?

Tags: git

This is a Linux 2.6 kernel repository. I git clone it to my local host.

After that. I didn't make any change. But when I "git status". I found 13 modified files. I want to discard them, but I can't.

```
> luke@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/linuxkernel/linux-2.6$ git
> status
> # On branch master
> # Changes not staged for commit:
> #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
> #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
> #
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_dscp.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_rateest.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ecn.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ttl.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_hl.h
> # modified:   net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ecn.c
> # modified:   net/netfilter/xt_dscp.c
> # modified:   net/netfilter/xt_hl.c
> # modified:   net/netfilter/xt_rateest.c
> # modified:   net/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.c
> #
> # Untracked files:
> #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
> #
> # samples/hidraw/ no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
> luke@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/linuxkernel/linux-2.6$ git
> checkout -- include/linux/netfilter/xt_connmark. h
> luke@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/linuxkernel/linux-2.6$ git
> status
> # On branch master
> # Changes not staged for commit:
> #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
> #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
> #
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_dscp.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_rateest.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ecn.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ttl.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_hl.h
> # modified:   net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ecn.c
> # modified:   net/netfilter/xt_dscp.c
> # modified:   net/netfilter/xt_hl.c
> # modified:   net/netfilter/xt_rateest.c
> # modified:   net/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.c
> #
> # Untracked files:
> #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
> #
> # samples/hidraw/ no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
> luke@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/linuxkernel/linux-2.6$ git
> checkout -- include/linux/netfilter/xt_dscp.h
> luke@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/linuxkernel/linux-2.6$ git
> status
> # On branch master
> # Changes not staged for commit:
> #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
> #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
> #
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_rateest.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ecn.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ttl.h
> # modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_hl.h
> # modified:   net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ecn.c
> # modified:   net/netfilter/xt_dscp.c
> # modified:   net/netfilter/xt_hl.c
> # modified:   net/netfilter/xt_rateest.c
> # modified:   net/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.c
> #
> # Untracked files:
> #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
> #
> # samples/hidraw/ no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
> luke@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/linuxkernel/linux-2.6$ 
>
```

edited:

```
luke@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/linuxkernel/linux-2.6$ git config -l
user.name=99999
user.email=99999
alias.co=checkout
core.editor=mate -w
core.edit=mate -w
core.excludesfile=/Users/luke/.gitignore_global
difftool.sourcetree.cmd=opendiff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
difftool.sourcetree.path=
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd=/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" -ancestor "$BASE" -merge "$MERGED"
mergetool.sourcetree.trustexitcode=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
```

edited: this is my diff file:

```
diff --git a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
index 2f2e48e..efc17a8 100644
--- a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
+++ b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
@@ -1,6 +1,31 @@
-#ifndef _XT_CONNMARK_H_target
-#define _XT_CONNMARK_H_target
+#ifndef _XT_CONNMARK_H
+#define _XT_CONNMARK_H

-#include <linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h>
+#include <linux/types.h>

-#endif /*_XT_CONNMARK_H_target*/
+/* Copyright (C) 2002,2004 MARA Systems AB <http://www.marasystems.com>
+ * by Henrik Nordstrom <hno@marasystems.com>
+ *
+ * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
+ * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
+ * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
+ * (at your option) any later version.
+ */
+
+enum {
+   XT_CONNMARK_SET = 0,
+   XT_CONNMARK_SAVE,
+   XT_CONNMARK_RESTORE
+};
+
+struct xt_connmark_tginfo1 {
+   __u32 ctmark, ctmask, nfmask;
+   __u8 mode;
+};
+
+struct xt_connmark_mtinfo1 {
+   __u32 mark, mask;
+   __u8 invert;
+};
+
+#endif /*_XT_CONNMARK_H*/
diff --git a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h
index 648e0b3..15f8932 100644
--- a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h
+++ b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h
@@ -1,26 +1,31 @@
-/* x_tables module for setting the IPv4/IPv6 DSCP field
+/* x_tables module for matching the IPv4/IPv6 DSCP field
  *
  * (C) 2002 Harald Welte <laforge@gnumonks.org>
- * based on ipt_FTOS.c (C) 2000 by Matthew G. Marsh <mgm@paktronix.com>
  * This software is distributed under GNU GPL v2, 1991
  *
  * See RFC2474 for a description of the DSCP field within the IP Header.
  *
- * xt_DSCP.h,v 1.7 2002/03/14 12:03:13 laforge Exp
+ * xt_dscp.h,v 1.3 2002/08/05 19:00:21 laforge Exp
 */
-#ifndef _XT_DSCP_TARGET_H
-#define _XT_DSCP_TARGET_H
-#include <linux/netfilter/xt_dscp.h>
+#ifndef _XT_DSCP_H
+#define _XT_DSCP_H
+
 #include <linux/types.h>

-/* target info */
-struct xt_DSCP_info {
+#define XT_DSCP_MASK   0xfc    /* 11111100 */
+#define XT_DSCP_SHIFT  2
+#define XT_DSCP_MAX    0x3f    /* 00111111 */
+
+/* match info */
+struct xt_dscp_info {
    __u8 dscp;
+   __u8 invert;
 };

-struct xt_tos_target_info {
-   __u8 tos_value;
+struct xt_tos_match_info {
    __u8 tos_mask;
+   __u8 tos_value;
+   __u8 invert;
 };

-#endif /* _XT_DSCP_TARGET_H */
+#endif /* _XT_DSCP_H */
diff --git a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h
index ecadc40..41c456d 100644
--- a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h
+++ b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h
@@ -1,15 +1,6 @@
-#ifndef _XT_MARK_H
-#define _XT_MARK_H
+#ifndef _XT_MARK_H_target
+#define _XT_MARK_H_target

-#include <linux/types.h>
+#include <linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h>

-struct xt_mark_tginfo2 {
-   __u32 mark, mask;
-};
-
-struct xt_mark_mtinfo1 {
-   __u32 mark, mask;
-   __u8 invert;
-};
-
-#endif /*_XT_MARK_H*/
+#endif /*_XT_MARK_H_target */
diff --git a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_rateest.h b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_rateest.h
index d40a619..6605e20 100644
--- a/include/linux/netfilter/xt_rateest.h
+++ b/include/linux/netfilter/xt_rateest.h
@@ -1,37 +1,15 @@
-#ifndef _XT_RATEEST_MATCH_H
-#define _XT_RATEEST_MATCH_H
+#ifndef _XT_RATEEST_TARGET_H
+#define _XT_RATEEST_TARGET_H
```

Due to Stack Overflow length limit. Only part of diff file can be copied here.

still need help

Comment: can you do a 'git config -l' in /linux-2.6 and paste the output?

Comment: Seeing the output of `git diff` wouldn't hurt as well.

Comment: @DavidDegea I have the same problem, `git reset --hard HEAD`, `git checkout -- .` didn't help. Have you managed to solve it?

Comment: I ran into this problem, too.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

A `git reset --hard HEAD` should solve the problem.

Comment: These changes are not staged (as they are listed under `Changes not staged for commit`), but hard reset should work anyway.

Comment: @KL-7: yes, now I noticed. I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: not working . ALso ,i tried "git config core.filemode false", then to reset. still...

Comment: then you really need to get the output of git diff, because the only remaining possibility I can think of would be the line endings (a very small chance)

Comment: @prusswan, I added diff here.

Comment: This is not good answer.  It's the real reason for the question.

Comment: is there any way to only reset modified files (and not deleted files)

Answer (score 27):

By entering these commands in succession.

```
git stash
git stash drop
```

`git stash` stores modified files on a stack for later retrieval.

`git stash drop` discards them.

Comment: more safe with this :)

Answer (score 23):

You can use:

```
git checkout .
```

To understand the difference between `git checkout` and `git reset` refer to the following question  :

[What's the difference between "git reset" and "git checkout"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639342/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-and-git-checkout)

Answer (score 17):

It happens because the linux kernel includes files with the same name (but different cases):

```
include/linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h 
include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
```

Answer (score 16):

To restore:

> *modified: specific_filename*

`git checkout <specific_filename>`

It's safer than removing all files at once using `git checkout .`.

Comment: This is the right answer, to remove specific modified file. +1

Answer (score 8):

this problem was caused, for me, by a non-case-sensitive filesystem (e.g. on Mac OS).  You can either create a case-sensitive disk image and mount it and do your git work on there, or use a different OS to do your development.

Answer (score 6):

You can remove untracked files with clean as well

```
git clean -f
```

Answer (score 3):

The question is similar to [Strange behaviour of Git: mysterious changes cannot be undone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893827/strange-behaviour-of-git-mysterious-changes-cannot-be-undone)

You need a  case-insensitive filesystem.  If your PC is Apple MAC like me, you can create Case-sensitive disk.

```
hdiutil create -type SPARSE -fs 'Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+' -size 25g ~/android.dmg

hdiutil resize -size <new-size-you-want>g ~/android.dmg.sparseimage

# mount the android file image
function mountAndroid { hdiutil attach ~/android.dmg.sparseimage -mountpoint /Volumes/android; }

# unmount the android file image
function umountAndroid() { hdiutil detach /Volumes/android; }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's another possibility where the issue is filemode-related. In that case you may try `git config core.filemode false`

More info: [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-mode-changes-chmod)

Edit:

Another possibility would be the line endings, try setting `git config core.autocrlf true|false|input` and see if it makes any difference.

More info: [Why should I use core.autocrlf=true in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git)

Comment: None of several answers in different questions worked for me, but this

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to remove all the files and modifications that differ from your **origin** branch but would like to keep all the ignored files (ex. node_modules, .vscode, .idea etc..) the best choice is to combine these two commands:

```
 git reset --hard && git clean -f
```

This will reset all modified files and will clean all the unstaged ones.