# Git shows file contents changed after clone

Tags: git, osx-yosemite

On OS X when cloning a repository immediately after cloning it, it shows two files (Markdown-Files) as modified.

But it's not the line endings that are marked as changed but the content instead has changed, specifically some casings and a date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cloning a git repo, and it already has a dirty working directory... Whaaaaa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383426/cloning-a-git-repo-and-it-already-has-a-dirty-working-directory-whaaaaa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these questions:

- [Cloning a git repo, and it already has a dirty working directory... Whaaaaa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383426)
- [Strange behaviour of Git: mysterious changes cannot be undone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893827)

This problem is caused by the OS X filesystem being case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks, the folder in question existed twice in the origin with different casing and file contents.