# Git clone issue - Non Discardable changes are generated

Tags: git, macos, github, bitbucket

I've cloned a repository from Github (same occurred from Bitbucket too).

After cloning, strange changes are generated. - non-discardable files.

After cloning, `mack.jpg` and `thumb_mack.jpg` are displayed as changed.
[image]

When I discard the files, `Mack.jpg` and `thumb_Mack.jpg` are displayed this time.
[image]

And if I discard again, this happens again and again - repeating.

This happens on other branches too - I've staged these files and moved to another branch, but the same.

I really don't want to add a new commit for this.

Please help me. Is there anyone who knows why this is happening?

Comment: It seems you've got a case sensitivity mismatch between the Mac operating system and Git. To Git, _Mack.jpg_ and _mack.jpg_ are two different files. To the Mac, they are the same file.

Comment: I can see your file names are different from the above screenshots. Once have look at this too [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893827/strange-behaviour-of-git-mysterious-changes-cannot-be-undone)

Comment: Thanks, matt and Satya Vinay. You saved my life.