# Git Repository Not Clean

Tags: git

I am getting a weird issue with Git repository not being clean, this is right after cloning it. I tried several different workarounds and no luck.

Note that I don't think I can't just copy all the file to another directory and copy back with a new git repo because we want to keep the git commit history.

- Tried to `git add .` from root directory and recommit but the files won't add.
- There's not `.gitignore` file in the root directory of the repo...I also checked `/Users/user` directory also and there's no extra `.gitignore` file
- Checked within the directory where files are not committing for extra `.git` directory but there was none
- Tried `git checkout -- <file>` and reset file but does not work
- Tried `git add --force` and it does not work

Was wondering if anyone else had any ideas?

**Update 1**

Few things I have noticed

- The committed file on GitHub have 257 lines, but after I do a fresh pull it locally, the local version only have 89 lines.
- If I do `git rm --cached` to remove the file, I am able to *delete* the *unstaged* files and commit those, but I loses the change difference of those files.

Comment: what does ```git status``` say?

Comment: can you paste the error you get ?

Comment: @Edmundo ```git status``` just says i have changes not staged for commit

Comment: @Thanga i am not getting an errors, the git commands are just not really doing anything, like ```git add .``` doesn't do anything to add the files

Comment: Then git add should add the files that you have with pending changes. Can you make sure you are running ```git add .``` from the _root_ of the repository?

Comment: @Edmundo i am running from the root of the repo, ```git add .``` doesn't do anything
https://pastebin.com/sjpK3yBV

Comment: This looks an awful lot like the usual CRLF vs LF-only *or* case-folding-file-names problem. For an example of the latter, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/38248208/1256452

Comment: @torek i don't think it is, i did a ```git diff``` of the file and it doesn't seem like a line feed issue

Comment: That's why I sugggested the case-folded-file-names thing as well. For instance Linux has both foo.h and FOO.H files; if you check out such a repository on Windows or Mac, using a default case-folding file *system*, the work-tree file is just one of those two names, so that the *other* file is "modified". You mentioned `/Users` which suggests MacOS.

Comment: Is your os x file system set up as case **sensitive** or case **insensitive**?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it should be case sensitive

Comment: @torek i get the same result if i pull to a linux system though

Comment: Why should it be case sensitive? The default for os x file system is case insensitive. Did you check or do you assume?

Comment: Try issuing a `git ls-files` and see if you have multiples of the files that are shown as unstaged, with different case combinations.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen sorry, it is case insensitive, also ```git ls-files``` provided a huge list, is there certain thing i should be looking for?

Comment: Yes, try to find the filenames that are causing problems, see if they exist more than once just with a casing difference, such as `File1.txt` vs `file1.txt` (F vs. f)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ok, so i looked through all the files with ```git ls-files``` and it seem like there are files with case issues. Let me see if I can fix this...