# git cannot add or checkout some files

Tags: git, kernel

I use git to clone this repo, https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git

After done, I find some files are changed, shown by `git status`.

```
 M include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
 M include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h
 M include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_MARK.h
 M include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.h
 M include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.h
 M include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h
 M include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_TTL.h
 M include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_HL.h
 M net/netfilter/xt_DSCP.c
 M net/netfilter/xt_HL.c
 M net/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.c
 M net/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.c
 M tools/memory-model/litmus-tests/Z6.0+pooncelock+poonceLock+pombonce.litmus
```

I try to use `git checkout -- .`, `git add -A`, `git stash`, `git reset --hard HEAD`(and `^HEAD`) and create a new branch, but all of them cannot work, these changes not disappeared.

My system is MacOS(I just want to read code and use git).

git version 2.19.1

Here is a content in .git/config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Those files aren't important for me, but I want to fix the problem.

By the way, There is no matter on my another remote linux machine.

Comment: Are those files important for you? you can use `git reset --hard` if those files not important

Comment: @DarrylR.Norbert I have tried, and it doesn't work. Those files aren't important, but I want to fix the problem

Comment: Taking `net/netfilter/xt_DSCP.c` for example, there is another file `net/netfilter/xt_dscp.c`. This is a problem in Windows because it's case insensitive. `net/netfilter/xt_DSCP.c` keeps being overwritten by `net/netfilter/xt_dscp.c` and therefore it's always modified.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7383426/1256452 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/8273823/1256452 both cover this case (not sure which of these to use as duplicate, and I know there is at least one more that I have seen in the past). I think I can add both as duplicates, actually...

Comment: Thanks, @ElpieKay. I try to set ignorecase to false, all being fine.

Comment: I set to false still did not fixed this problem. @Vonfry